# How would you avoid context/class explosion in this case with MSpec?

Tags: mspec

I love mspec. It is great for providing key examples in way that is easy to communicate with non technical people but sometimes I find it provides an unnecessary verbosity, specifically an explosion of classes.

Take the following example.

I want to model the movement of a knight piece in chess. Assuming the knight is not near any other piece or the boundaries of the board there are 8 possible moves that knight can have I want to cover each of these possibilities but to be frank I am too lazy to write 8 separate specifications (8 classes). I know that I can be clever with behaviours and inheritance but as I want to cover the 8 valid moves I cannot see how I can do it with out 8 `because`s so therefore 8 separate classes.

What is the best way to cover these scenarios with mspec?

Some code.

```
public class Knight
{
    public string Position {get; private set;}

    public Knight(string startposition)
    {
         Position = startposition;
    }

    public void Move
    {
          // some logic in here that allows a valid move pattern and sets positions
    }


}
```

What I might do.

```
[Subject(typeof(Knight),"Valid movement")]
public class when_moving_the_knight
{
     Establish that = () => knight =new Knight("D4");
     Because of = ()=> knight.Move("B3");
     It should_update_position = ()=> knight.Position.ShouldEqual("B3");
     It should_not_throw;
     /// etc..    
}
```

But not 8 times.

Comment: I think that you might want to provide some more information on your project for someone trying to answer to your question in a proper way. From my point of view I would test it with one "Because" clause (Because the_knight_is_in_e4) followed by 8 different "It" clauses (It should_be_able_to_move_to_f6, etc.), but I don't know if in your case this would apply. It looks odd to me that you need 8 different contexts, perhaps your classes or your tests might need some sort of refactoring.

Comment: @brizio the trouble I have with `because knight_is_at_e4` is that I don't know where to do the move now. I can't do it in the `it` as I am asserting there

Comment: one thing to ask yourself is why you care if there is a "class explosion". Is that getting in the way of other people reading your code and understanding it? Does it get in the way of anyone who reads the end report (if you have anyone who does, we often don't). Or are you just concerned because it "seems like a lot of classes" or something along those lines?

Comment: I can answer from my perspective. I care about class explosion because it's not fun to write. It feels like a lot of sytax tax just to make the compiler happy. One thing I'm realizing is that context/spec is generally harder for other developers to read and understand intent (as compared to given when then). I think class explosion might actually be easier for new devs to read compared to data structure iteration. But I tend to prefer the latter because it's fewer key strokes and more concise. Concerning readability of output, I believe either should produce easily readable output.

Comment: In my experience, it is better to optimize for code readability/scanability than it is to optimize for "fun to write", "key strokes" or "conciseness". In other words, I would consider it a bad idea to forsake readability/scanability for any of those things that you prefer.

Comment: I was simply posing the question because the word "class explosion" was used. If he had used the word "test explosion" I don't know that anyone would have cared. It's all about context. If you have lots of scenarios to test, you have lots of tests. Sure, you could employ a RowTest or table test to reduce that number, but then I would recommend using a framework meant for that. MSpec is not. NSpec allows it, but it's a bit hard to follow. Of course, RowTests are always a bit hard to follow by their nature. As it turns out, there is a perfectly valid way to use MSpec in this scenario. See below.

Comment: @Aaron I'm lazy - I don't want to write 8 classes and all the ceremony that surrounds it. In my mind the context is 'moving the knight' and to me that should be covered in one class. The solutions that you have kindly provided seems like a compromise to me. Trying to implement multiline `its` are just emulating a standard unit testing framework and losing the strength of context/specification I guess that 8 classes is the approach I would write with MSpec. That's the one I feel more comfortable with.

Comment: John, I'm not sure I understand. On one hand, you want the context to be "moving the knight", on the other hand you reject my suggestion that the observation can include the "act" such as "it should be able to move up two and to the right one". I'm not sure that you can want one and reject the other. Also, who said anything about multi line its? You could write it in one line still, that's what helper methods are for. My main point is that this sort of thing matters much less than what makes the code easier to understand if you didn't write it. Optimize for that and you'll be fine.

Comment: hmm reading more rspec code its clearer to me how it works and how I've been using mspec. All the code examples I've seen have used Establish/Because extensively. I'm not sure I I like what I see but at least I have a better frame of reference.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I couldn't tell you the best way to do that in MSpec. But I've experienced a similar class explosion problem with MSpec when using it in similar circumstances. I don't know if you have ever tried RSpec. In RSpec contexts and specifications are built up within the confines of executable code. What that means is you can create a data structure, iterate on it, and create several contexts and specs using one block of code. This becomes especially handy when you are trying to specify how something based in mathematics behaves (prime factors,tic tac toe, chess, etc...). A single pattern of behavior can be specified across each member of a set of given and expected values.

This example is written in NSpec, a context/spec framework for C# modeled after RSpec. I purposefully left a failing spec. I just went down this kata far enough to find a place to use iteration. The failing spec forces you to resolve the shortcomings of the naive implementation.

Here's another example of prime factor kata: http://nspec.org/#dolambda

Output:

```
describe Knight
  when moving 2 back and 1 left
    when a knight at D4 is moved to B3
      knight position should be B3
    when a knight at C4 is moved to A3
      knight position should be A3 - FAILED - String lengths are both 2. Strings differ at index 0., Expected: "A3", But was: "B3", -----------^

**** FAILURES ****

describe Knight. when moving 2 back and 1 left. when a knight at C4 is moved to A3. knight position should be A3.
String lengths are both 2. Strings differ at index 0., Expected: "A3", But was: "B3", -----------^
   at ChessSpecs.describe_Knight.<>c__DisplayClass5.<when_moving_2_back_and_1_left>b__4() in c:\Users\matt\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ChessSpecs\ChessSpecs\describe_Knight.cs:line 23

2 Examples, 1 Failed, 0 Pending
```

Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NSpec;

class describe_Knight : nspec
{
    void when_moving_2_back_and_1_left()
    {
        new Each<string,string> { 
            {"D4", "B3"},
            {"C4", "A3"},
        }.Do( (start, moveTo) =>
        {
            context["when a knight at {0} is moved to {1}".With(start,moveTo)] = () =>
            {
                before = () =>
                {
                    knight = new Knight(start);
                    knight.Move(moveTo);
                };
                it["knight position should be {0}".With(moveTo)] = () => knight.Position.should_be(moveTo);
            };
        });
    }
    Knight knight;
}

class Knight
{
    public Knight(string position)
    {
        Position = position;
    }

    public void Move(string position)
    {
        Position = "B3";
    }

    public string Position { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Its the way you want to. It should be able to move from here to there, it should be able to move from here(2) to there(2), etc. Very common pattern in rspec but not so much in MSpec because it's generally overused so no one ever talks about it for fear of guiding the wrong way. This is a great spot to use this though. You're describing the behavior of the Knight's moving.

You can describe it even better by being more specific in your Its. It should be able to move up two and to the right one, it should be able to move up two and to the left one. It should not be able to move onto a friendly piece, etc.

Yes, you'll need to put more than one line of code in your It, but that's OK. At least in my opinion.

Comment: With this approach aaron I goings to have to reset state in my its. This seems like a mangling of the Establish, Because It (AAA) pattern

Comment: MSpec isn't a AAA framework. It's a context/specification framework with constructs to write AAA tests if they're appropriate. Your context is a chess piece in a chess board and you're specifying or observing that it can move from this spot to that, the other spot to that other spot, etc. Ultimately, it's best to just not be too pedantic about ideas like AAA and just do what makes sense and is easy to follow. If that means resetting state in each It (and/or using [SetupForEachSpecification]) then do it.

Answer (score 1):

From what I see your design states that the Knight would throw an exception if moved in an invalid position. In this case I think that your method has two different responsibilities, one for checking a valid move and the other for doing the correct move or throwing. I would suggest to split your method into the two distinct responsibilities.

For this specific case I would extract a method for checking whether a move is valid or not, and then calling it from your move method. Something like that:

```
public class Knight
{
    internal bool CanMove(string position)
    {
        // Positioning logic here which returns true or false
    }

    public void Move(string position)
    {
        if(CanMove(position))
            // Actual code for move
        else
            // Throw an exception or whatever
    }
}
```

this way you could test the logic inside CanMove for testing valid positions for a given Knight (which you can do with a single test class and different "It"s), then make just one test for the Move method to see if it fails when given an invalid position.